# Understanding regex in Javascript .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I shouldn't say I actually have a "problem" (the code seems to... work? Although one time it through an error in the console possibly due to environmental reasons), but I'm picking apart a piece of code and I see this:

```js
key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
```

"key" is passed into the function containing this line. As you might expect, it's a string that's ultimately used as the needle in a haystack.

It's sanitizing *something*, but I can't figure out what it's sanitizing (primarily because I don't have any fluency in regex I guess). JSLint is barking about something also (Unexpected ']') but I think it's a false positive because it's not parsing the regex.

Wasn't sure to ask this at Stack Overflow or at Code Review, but it's not really "review" so here it is.

Any insight from you regexy type people would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's for the `jQuery` tag and not for the `javascript` tag **?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got it right it replaces `[` with `\[` and `]` with `\]`, so basically an escaping of square brackets.

Comment: Would love to know a good way of doing it... that should go without saying... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

These all do the same thing (globally)

```
var key = 'a[b] [c] [][]d'.replace(/[\[]/g,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/g,"\\\]"); 
print(key);
var key = 'a[b] [c] [][]d'.replace(/[\[]/g,'\\[').replace(/[\]]/g,'\\]'); 
print(key);
var key = 'a[b] [c] [][]d'.replace(/([\[\]])/g,"\\$1"); 
print(key);
```

Comment: Useful! Not sure I want to print out to my printer, but I know what you meant. ;-)